# htaccess redirect to subfolder with exception

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I've searched quite a lot without finding a solution.

I have a wordpress blog in `/_wp` and something else in `/other`

What I'm trying to is that every request gets redirected to the WordPress. Except those to `/other` and its child directories. I also want the access to the blog to be rewritten. Few examples to make it clear:

```
/ --> /_wp/

/ablogpost --> /_wp/ablogpost

/other --> /other

/other/bingou --> /other/bingou
```

I've tried a few things but what seems the most logical to me is:

- don't touch the .htaccess of /_wp/ and of /other/
- edit the .htaccess of the root '/' by adding:

  ```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?mywebsite.com$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(/other|/other/.*)$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /_wp/$1
  ```

If you could tell me what is wrong there it would be great!

## EDIT

After changing the index the subfolders were still not working here was my .htaccess back then:

```
IndexIgnore .htaccess */.??* *~ *# */HEADER* */README* */_vti*
<Limit GET POST>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
   allow from all
</Limit>
<Limit PUT DELETE>
   order deny,allow
   deny from all
</Limit>
AuthName site.com
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

## EDIT 2

In the end it was a host problem thanks for your help though! Your answer works just well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow this : http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory

Your wordpress install is already in its own directory, so you just have to :

**Copy `/_wp/.htaccess` to `/.htaccess`**

**Copy `/_wp/index.php` to `/index.php`**

**Edit `/index.php` :**

`require('./_wp/wp-blog-header.php');`

**Edit `/.htaccess`**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Well that doesn't entirely answer to the question. Ok now my redirect to the wordpress is much cleaner. 
However I still can't access to my directory /other/ (I get 404)
Moreover I've got a directory /img that is used in different places on the website. I can access to .png files but I can't access to gif files.
Any idea for that?

Comment: This should work, show me your actual `/.htaccess` file (edit your question)

Comment: Did you try to remove everything except wordpress rewrite rules ?

Comment: yes still doesn't work...
I'm down to a .htaccess that is exactly the one you posted. I still can't access to gifs and to my other folders' php files. Though if I go in /others/ I've got the list of all the files in the directory...